# Unable to Create new tables in Postgres (Django rest API)

Tags: django, postgresql, rest

[image]**File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists**

Can someone guide me to solve this error?

Comment: Can you drop/delete your DB and run your migrations again?

Comment: Hii..Tried dropping the DB but getting errors    Error message
ERROR: database "project" is being accessed by other users DETAIL: There are 2 other sessions using the database.

Comment: I have posted the errors in my comment

Comment: Drop those other sessions, kill the applications that are connected to your DB

Comment: Can you tell me the commands to kill the applications!

Comment: Even after dropping the DB I am getting the same error `emergencycontact=models.IntegerField(default=None)` the error triggered while adding an extra field

Comment: It's a non-nullable integer field, set the default to a valid integer like `0` - `emergencycontact=models.IntegerField(default=0)`? If it's actually nullable then pass `null=True` to the field - `emergencycontact=models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)`?

Comment: Hii While migrations the emergencycontact field was added but while manage.py migrate   `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" ` already exists got this error

Comment: Add the full traceback from the error/command to your question, if you have completely dropped the DB then you shouldn't be getting this error